# randomly selection of images from File

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have a file that contains a 400 images. What I want is to separate this file into two files: train_images and test_images.

The train_images should contains 150 images selected randomly, and all these images must be different from each other. Then, the test_images should also contains 150 images selected randomly, and should be different from each other, even from the images selected in the file train_images.

I begin by writing a code that aims to select a random number of images from a Faces file and put them on train_images file. I need your help in order to respond to my behavior described above.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;


 Train_images='train_faces';
 mkdir(Train_images);


ImageFiles = dir('Faces');
   totalNumberOfImages = length(ImageFiles)-1;
   scrambledList = randperm(totalNumberOfImages);
   numberIWantToUse = 150;
   loop_counter = 1;
   for index = scrambledList(1:numberIWantToUse)
        baseFileName = ImageFiles(index).name;
        str = fullfile('faces', baseFileName); % Better than STRCAT

        face = imread(str);

        imwrite( face, fullfile(Train_images, ['hello' num2str(index) '.jpg']));

        loop_counter = loop_counter + 1;
   end
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: so why can't you use the images from 151:300 as test images?

Comment: Ah can we use this method? is  it efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good to me. When you implement the test, you can re-run the `scrambledList = randperm(totalNumberOfImages);` then select the first 150 elements in `scrambledList` as you did in training process.

You can also directly re-initialize the loop:

```
for index = scrambledList(numberIWantToUse+1 : 2*numberIWantToUse)
   ... % same thing you wrote in your training loop

end
```

with this approach, your test sample will be completely different from the training sample.

Comment: As always:), Thank youuu:))

Comment: I will appreciate very much your answer if you can help in my new question:D

Comment: really sorry this time I cannot help. I'm not very good at the file and directory operations..... I saw someone else answered your question, and hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have the Bioinformatics Toolbox, you can use [`crossvalind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) using the parameter `HoldOut`:

This is an example. `train`and `test` are logical arrays, so you can use `find`to get the actual indexes:

```
ImageFiles = dir('Faces');
ImageFilesIndexes = ones(1,length(ImageFiles )) %Use a numeric array instead the char array
proportion = 150/400; %Testing set
[train,test] = crossvalind('holdout',ImageFilesIndexes,proportion );
training_files = ImageFiles(train); %250 files: It is better to use more data to train
testing_files = ImageFiles(test); %150 files

%Then do whatever you like with the files
```

Other possibilities are [`dividerand`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/nnet/ref/dividerand.html) ( Neural Network Toolbox) and [`cvpartition`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/cvpartition.html) (Statistics Toolbox)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. I run your code (I am using the matlab version R2013a), but unfortunately I got this error: Error using grp2idx (line 117)
A grouping variable must be a categorical, numeric, or logical vector, a cell vector of strings, or a
2D character array.

Comment: @Christina Please, check the edited version of the code. You can use a numeric array of the same length as your char array as the input.

Comment: Ok it works now, but I got: training_files (437x1 struct) and testing_files (0x1 struct).

Comment: And how can I open these files

Comment: @Christina OK, I forgot that `crossvalind` needs all ones to make the split. Check out the new code. Now it works as you wanted.

Comment: ok but how to read the images into these files ? ant the training images contains 287 images.

Comment: To read the images, you need to use the same piece of code you are using in your example... `baseFileName = training_files(index).name;str = fullfile('faces', baseFileName);face = imread(str);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help:) really I appreciate very much your help, thanks again